# Ko3 - URL Rewriting problem - Removing index.php

Tags: url-rewriting, kohana

I'm developing a website using Kohana 3 (1rst time I use a framework). Locally, everything works perfectly. At the moment, I have a default template controller, a multi-language support and my 'index.php' is correctly removed. So before going further, I tested if it worked on my server and I got an endless loop.

I followed the tutorial from the unofficial wiki for the multi-language implementation: http://www.kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=example_of_a_multi-language_website

A redirection to the default language occurs if the language is not specified in the uri so I figured the problem might have come from there even though it worked locally, so I removed it to see what happens without the redirection. Now, I can see my home page, but whatever the uri is in the web browser, the home page will always be called. I inserted the following line in my home view to check what the uri was:
request::instance()->uri() and effectively, the uri is always: /en/home/

I put the index.php back (in the bootstrap) and everything worked fine again, even with the redirection to the default language.

My first guess was that the uri isn't rewritten correctly, so I tried to change the .htaccess but no success...

Here's my .htaccess:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
# Installation directory
RewriteBase /dev/
# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
</Files>
# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system)/ - [F,L]
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

(btw I also tried the other RewriteRule in the unofficial wiki, doesn't work either)

Additional info:
Host: WebHostingPad
Apache: v2.2.11
PHP: 5.2.9

Rewrite_Module is activated

Thank you, I would really appreciate your help because I've been trying to fix this for days now and it's really starting to annoy me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` which returned no value...

This issue can be solved by adding the following line to the php.ini:

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you have to change in order to get rid of index.php in URL is to set the 'index_file' param in Kohana::init ( bootstrap.php ) to FALSE ( everything else can cause an error ).

So the Kohana::init looks like this;

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'      => '/',
    'index_file'    => FALSE,
```

));

If it worked with the original .htaccess, there's no need to change it at all.